# Definition of member functions in the scope of the enclosing class for a nested class

Tags: c++

In the c++ draft standard we have this statement in [class.nest]:

> 2 Member functions and static data members of a nested class can be defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of their class. *[Example:*
>
> ```
> struct enclose {
>     struct inner {
>         static int x;
>         void f(int i);
>     };
> };
>
> int enclose::inner::x = 1;
> void enclose::inner::f(int i) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

My confusion is that if this is possible then why isn't the [following possible](http://ideone.com/TZmpT3):

```
struct enclose {
    struct inner {
        void f(int i);
    };
    void inner::f(int i) {}
};
```

> error: cannot define member function 'enclose::inner::f' within 'enclose'
>        void inner::f(int i) {}

*Doesn't the definition of `f` lie in the same scope enclosing the definition of the `inner` class?*

*If not, then why is this not allowed? What issue is there with defining this function in the class scope?*

Comment: In the second case you have a class scope, and not a namespace scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording you cited says it can be defined in **namespace scope**. You're attempting to define it within `struct enclose`, which is **class scope**, not namespace scope.

Comment: As a follow up, why have this limited to *namespace scope* what would be the problem with being able to define it in class scope? (i will add this to the question as well)\

Comment: @Ben I don't think the issue is that there's a problem, but that it's unnecessary.    The main point of defining member functions outside of the class definition is that it hides implementation details from users, since they don't need to know how your class works under the hood to be able to use it.  Placing nested class member function definitions inside the enclosing class' definition doesn't actually hide their implementation, because you need to use the enclosing class' definition either way.  As such, it was most likely considered unnecessarily obfuscated, and thus not allowed.

Comment: @JustinTime Yeah, i came to the same conclusion, if you where going to define it in `enclose` why not just go ahead and define in `inner`.

Comment: It also wouldn't prevent them from being implicitly declared as `inline`, because they would still be defined in every translation unit that uses the class.